# Error, probably about memory

Tags: android, memory, android-studio, out-of-memory

So i was testing my app, and ir ocourred and error in one point, i saw the stack trace and it was on a line that i didn't even change and it was working before. But looking to the stack trace i think the problem is lack of memory.
Here's the line of the error (was in the line setContentView..)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agencia_figueira);

    Button buttonFigueira = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMenu);
    buttonFigueira.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(agenciaFigueira.this, MainActivity.class);
                    agenciaFigueira.this.startActivity(i);
                }
            }
    );
```

But one of the lines of the stack trace was : Failed to allocate a 10603020 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 7MB until OOM

If it is lack of memory how can i fix it ? :x

Comment: post the complete stack trace from logcat

Comment: It sounds plausible: the error says you tried to allocate 10MB, but only had 419K bytes free.  Q: Does the traceback show exactly what you were trying to allocate?  Understanding that is key to resolving the problem.,

Comment: I'm new at this stackoverflow, how can i put here the hole stack trace? i tried the same way as i put code, but gave me an error :x

Comment: I smell a big image being loaded as an image view resource in that xml.

Comment: But even if that's the problem i don't understand.. I have a bunch of images, that's true. But isn't an app suppose to have a lot more memory ? I ran out of memory because of a bunch of images O.o What happens do the more comples app's ? how is there memory for them ? :P

Comment: It's just a doubt. How big are these images? (in MBs).

Comment: I checked, the biggest one i have is 791Kb

Comment: Well, it's not that big. So, I assume you're testing with a somewhat low-end or old device. However, that's not the device's fault. Make sure you have multiple scaled versions matching the different display resolutions (i.e. scaled versions for `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, ...etc).

Comment: I'm not testing in an actual device. I'm testing in android studio in a virtual device

Comment: So, make sure you have at least about 512MB free RAM for the virtual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You absolutely need to re-examine your stack traceback ... and possibly add debug statements ... to determine exactly *where* you're asking for 10MB (and failing).  You need to identify the *specific resource* in question before you can determine a solution.
2. If you're using an emulator ... then you have the luxury of being able to specify the image's memory size (something you often cannot do with a physical handset).  Make sure the emulator has a "reasonable" amount of RAM.  512MB is generally a good number.
3. Android Studio has *excellent* tools for checking memory utilization.  For example:

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

[image]

4. Please post back what you find!

Comment: Where can i see the ram of my emulator ? i saw the details, and the only thing about ram is hw.ramSize: 1536, what exatlly is that ? :b
And another question, let's see my emulator can't allocate this amout of memory, bc of lack of ram, if i use a real device, if i connect my phone with USB and try it there i wont have that problem anymore right ?

Comment: Again: the main thing is you need to *identify the specific resource you're trying to allocate at the point of failure*!  Q: What does the traceback tell you?  Q: Have you tried debug monitor?  What "memory hogs" have you identified?  FYI, hw.ramSize 1536 is 1.5GB: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html.